# install oozie 4.3.0 on hadoop 2.7.3 Error

Tags: maven, hadoop, oozie, oozie-workflow

I am trying to install oozie 4.3.0 on hadoop 2.7.3, when I tried to create oozie distro. it is getting failed with the below error message.

```
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:4.3.0 (/home/hduser/setups/oozie-4.3.0/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:17 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo1.maven.org refused and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 21, column 13: Connection timed out (Connection timed out) -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:17 from/to central   (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo1.maven.org refused
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally   (DefaultModelBuilder.java:813)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:664)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:310)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:232)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:410)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:379)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:343)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:636)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:585)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:17 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo1.maven.org refused
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve    (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
```

also check setting.xml proxy tag it is mentioned correctly couldn't figure out what is the issue.

```
 <proxy>
  <id>myproxy</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <username>xxxx</username>
  <password>xxxx</password>
  <host>xxxx</host>
  <port>xxxx</port>
  <nonProxyHosts></nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

Comment: watch it my newly created blog to install oozie-4.3.0 on combination of hadoop-2.9.0 step by step,
https://oozie-4-3-0.blogspot.in/2017/12/installing-oozie-430-with-existing.html, at least have a look, may be some of the points are there to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Updated the proxy settings in /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml file instead of ${HOME}/.m2/settings.xml, it fixed the issue.